# gRPC Streaming - Handling buffer overrun

Tags: streaming, grpc, grpc-python, grpc-c++, buffer-overrun

What will happened in a gRPC streaming service, with a faster producer (server) than the consumer (client)?

- Can the message queue dynamically grow in size?
- If the buffer becomes full, are there mechanisms in place to handle message dropping? If so, how are the dropped messages selected (oldest, newest, random)?

Any insights or best practices for handling buffer overrun in gRPC streaming would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What languages (server and client) are you using? Depends on the languages the behavior at the API level might be different. The messages should not be dropped though (more like the server will be told to slow down).

Comment: C++ for server and python for client. @yijiem

Comment: You can check out here which introduces the concept of flow control in gRPC: https://grpc.io/docs/guides/flow-control/